# Bind events in iframe content even when change url

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to bind a envent when form is submitted inside an iframe, but i'm having some problems:

**First attempt:**

I tried to bind the envent when the page loads, it worked, but the event only is binded when the page loads entirely.

```
$('#mainFrame').on("load", function()
{ 

    $('#mainFrame').contents().find('form').submit(function(){

        $('#overlay').addClass("overlay");

    });
});
```

Then I tried to use the ready event

```
$('#mainFrame').ready(function()
{ 

    $('#mainFrame').contents().find('form').submit(function(){

        $('#overlay').addClass("overlay");

    });
});
```

But it isn't is called when the url is changed.

**Second attempt:**

I tried to bind the event on every input inside the iframe, but I think it can't access iframe elements without .contents()

```
$('#mainFrame').on("click", 'input',function(){


     $('#overlay').addClass("overlay");

});
```

**PS:** Iframe page is from the same domain

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: To access an iframe's contents, you must wait until it has fully loaded, so bind events on load as you did the first example.

Comment: Some pages are too slow to fully load all the resources, i need something like .ready to bind the event right after the dom is loaded

Comment: Don't rely on an iframe to be ready on the spot. Instead of iframes, you can import html at designated areas of your main page using `.load()` or `.get()`.  If your content is huge, you might want to rewrite your layout in a way that your content is sectioned into smaller parts to be loaded on demand.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but i do not have karma. sorry for spam.

If on load happens to slow for you consider trigerring events from inside iframe, maybe add this code to form submit:

```
window.parent.jQuery(window.parent.document).trigger('iframestuff');
```

and in a parent page listen to it:

```
$(document).on('iframestuff', function(){ 
});
```

Comment: It's a possibility, but i'ts a program with at least 2 thousand pages with diferents templates, so it'll be better if i could solve this in the parent page